# Why is my security patch over a month old?

Tags: updates, security, 7.0-nougat, nexus-5x, nexus

I have a Nexus 5X with Google Fi as the servcice provider. `Settings > About Phone > System updates` shows:

```
Your system is up to date
Android version: 7.1.2
Security patch level: August 5, 2017
```

Checking for updates finds nothing new.

I'm concerned that my phone still doesn't have the [blueborne](https://www.armis.com/blueborne/) fix supposedly included in the [September 2017 security patch](https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/2017-09-01). Is it normal to go this long without receiving a security update? Is there any way to force an update? Is there any guideline on when devices are updated? The only relevant article I've found is [Check & update your Android version](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/4457705?hl=en), but that just tells me how long my device is supported, and not how soon I can expect to receive patches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Android Oreo's official debut, Nougat is no longer the "current" Android version, therefore Google doesn't officially patch it. On the other hand, Oreo for N5X has already undergone 3 iterations corresponding to Aug., Sept. and Oct. patches.

Oreo is supposed to come to your device in one of the phased rollouts, but if you're eager to get it, consider backing up data, unlocking bootloader (if you haven't already), then either manually flashing a [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/images) or flashing a custom ROM (FYI, LineageOS has ported over the Sept. patch even though its official release is still on Nougat).

Comment: I guess this is the answer, though it is disappointing to go so long without a securit update. You'd think they would keep delivering those to the old platform until they completely rolled out the new one.

Comment: Priorities... It's natural to expect us Nexus users to get left behind when Pixel is the new spotlight.